# Can I use stocks as margin for commodities futures?

Tags: futures, margin, margin-call

Last week, I bought 4 shares of emicro gold futures (https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/precious/e-micro-gold_contract_specifications.html) worth about 70k. I got a margin call for owning those gold despite having 400k worth of equities and having no other margin debt in my account.

Why did I get this margin call? I had 0 cash, but 400k worth of stocks. Is it because my equities don't count towards the maintenance margin of the futures contract? As far as I understood the maintenance margin is 1k per future contract in the link above, so I guess I would need 4k of cash (not stocks) in my account at all times to hold those 4 gold futures contracts?

I think the mistake I made was that despite having lots of stocks, I had no cash in my account. Can someone confirm this is what triggered my margin call?

Comment: Amazing stuff - what broker ?

Comment: The answers are yes, yes, and yes. Would you expect your broker to sell equities to cover your losses? Which ones?

Comment: I know hardly anything about futures but when there is an equity margin call and the account holder doesn't address it, the broker can and will sell any securities that he wants to in order to restore proper margin.

Comment: @DStanley Since I lost <1000$ and had 400k worth of equities and a massive cushion on my equities maintenance margin, I certainly wasn't expecting to get liquidated on my position, although I get your point. Seems somewhat absurd to have a totally different margin requirement for commodities than equities, it's not like i was going to go broke on 1/400th of my account in losses.

Comment: @BobBaerker Just want to say I really appreciate your answers on this website btw.

Comment: @user3586940 - Thanks, I appreciate you're saying that.  It may sound hokey or corny but part of it is a bit of Pay It Forward.  30+ years ago I was on the stock and option  bulletin boards on Prodigy and there were many experienced people who greatly helped me with my learning curve which needed a lot of work at that time :->).

Comment: @BobBaerker well it's working :)